# Wifi  stopped working in Windows Vista after using Ubuntu demo CD

Tags: 12.04, wireless, windows-vista

After trying the Ubuntu 12.04 demo cd, wifi has stopped working on my Windows vista machine. Before demo cd, wifi worked fine inside Windows

During demo CD (and every time I use it), WiFi works fine inside Ubuntu 12.04. Since first time I used demo CD, WiFi does not work anymore inside Windows vista. Windows says the hardware switch for WiFi is off, but it is on (and must be since it works under Ubuntu)

```
rfkill list all
```

Shows no blocks inside Ubuntu, but Windows still says hardware switch is off ever since the first time I used demo CD from Ubuntu

```
rfkill unblock wifi
```

has no effect

```
sudo lspci -v
```

shows network controller is Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] rev 02 and ethernet controller is Realtek RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit rev 01

Comment: should have mentioned this - sudo lspci -v shows network controller is Intel PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] rev 02 and ethernet controller is Realtek RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit rev 01

Comment: you can always [edit your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/135474/edit) and add the details

Comment: Once I was also experienced this problem with my Compaq system and I used HP Support application to turn wireless back in to operation.I think you someway unchecked the "enable wireless" on Network menu.This caused me on that occasion,after that I did not have done such a mistake.

Comment: If it is a laptop have you tried to shut it down and remove the battery for a minute? In either case you can try to reinstall it under Windows.  It seems to me that the problem might be that there might be firmware needed for your Realtek and the Ubuntu firmware might be incompatible with Windows.   The trick might be to find a way to get Windows to load the firmware it has for the device.

Comment: This unanswered question is about Windows Vista which is EOL and Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. Additionally OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years and the problem was likely solved by now although we will never learn the solution. VTC as `not reproducible`.